# Block outgoing connections for docker with iptables while allowing some IPs on Debian

Tags: debian, iptables, docker

I'm trying to block all outgoing connections for my docker containers while still allowing outgoing traffic to a specific IP and port. However when I block all outgoing ports, all incoming connections are blocked too.

Here is what I have now which works as it should. Blocking all http/https traffic while allowing some IPs

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o eth0 -j RETURN

iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j DROP
 
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -i eth0 --dport https -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j RETURN #Allow incoming HTTPS traffic
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -o eth0 --dport https -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j RETURN #Allow outgoing ESTABLISHED HTTPS traffic

iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -o eth0 -d yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy --dport https -j RETURN #Allow outgoing HTTPS for this IP
```

The issue comes when I try to block all outgoing ports with a rule like this:
`iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 0:65535 -j DROP`
With this rule all incoming and outgoing connections are dropped.

It works if I block port 0 to around 40000. Checking with `netstat -p` I can see that all incoming connections on 443 are forwarded? to a port around the 40000 range.

This server does not have a lan. The ip on eth0 is the same as the external public IP.

How do I block all outgoing connections without blocking the incoming connections?